# How do I connect these two faces together?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, faces, edges

This is somewhat difficult to explain, but I have been trying to fill in the gap between these two faces with a rectangular shape... As you can see here, this is the screenshot of what I am trying to fill in:

[image: What I am trying to fill in]

I'm essentially wanting it to be connected and then delete the edges in between so it forms a loop around the "building" I have so far... When I extrude the face, I can only delete one edge...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable the *Snap to Vertex* and the *Auto Merge* options:

[image]

Then move the edges on X and Y, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to snap to the vertex of the other edge:

[image]

Comment: For some reason it isn't merging or snapping... Any advice?

Comment: Never mind, I got it... Thanks :)